# Why doesn't 'For each' loop on a uninitialized array in Java

Tags: java, java-11

I have a program for a binary search in Java. The 'for-each' loop doesn't seem to increment the counter variable after taking input for the array. However, it does work with a regular 'for' loop. Why can't the 'for-each' loop increment the counter in this situation?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class binarySearch {
    public static int rank(int key, int[] a) {
        int lo = 0;
        int hi = a.length - 1;

        while (lo <= hi) {
            int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
            if (key > a[mid])
                lo = mid + 1;
            else if (key < a[mid])
                hi = mid - 1;
            else
                return mid;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the key to be searched");
        int key = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("\nEnter the number of elements in the array");
        int num = in.nextInt();
        int[] array = new int[num];

        for (int counter : array) {
            System.out.println("Enter the element of the array!");
            array[counter] = in.nextInt();
        }
        int result = rank(key, array);
        if (result == -1) {
            System.out.println("\n The given key is not found!\n");
        } else {
            System.out.println("\n The given key is found at position : " + (result + 1));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work Check out the links mentioned in the answer as well as the comments to get a better idea on how for-each works. Hope this helps.

Comment: As an aside to help with future questions: the binary search part isn't actually relevant here. Just printing out the array after populating it would show the problem. It's best to keep questions to a minimal example that demonstrates the problem. Not a big issue in this question, but worth knowing for future ones.

Comment: Yeah, sure thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've just created the array without populating it, so it will be full of default values. You're then iterating over the *values* of the elements of the array, which means that the value of `counter` is going to be 0 every time. This loop:

```
for(int counter : array )
{
    System.out.println("Enter the element of the array!");
    array[counter] = in.nextInt();
}
```

... is broadly equivalent to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    // Note: this will always be zero because the array elements are all zero to start with
    int counter = array[i]; 
    System.out.println("Enter the element of the array!");
    array[counter] = in.nextInt();
}
```

You don't actually want to iterate over the original values in the array at all - you just want to iterate from 0 to the length of the array (exclusive) which is easily done with the `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Enter the element of the array!");
    array[i] = in.nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The foreach loop does not iterate over the array indexes but over the array elements.

Answer (score 0):

Because in

```
    for(int counter : array )
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the element of the array!");
        array[counter] = in.nextInt();
    }
```

`counter` is not a counter. It is value from array.